# Why was 303 skipped in HTTP/1.0?

Tags: http, http-headers, 303-redirect

While looking back over HTTP response codes today I noticed that the 301, 302, and 304 response codes were defined in HTTP/1.0 but not the 303 response code.  Does anyone know why the number 303 was skipped in HTTP/1.0?

Comment: MDN states that the 303 code was [defined in HTTP/0.9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/HTTP_response_codes), although all other docs I've seen state that it was introduced with HTTP/1.1 (to resolve an issue with 302 implementations in HTTP/1.0). There are other gaps in the numbering, 203 for instance was inly introduced HTTP/1.1. I would _guess_ that a 303 was included in an initial working draft but simply didn't make the final cut?! Status codes wouldn't be renumbered since implementations would have already been developed I suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not skipped right away. As you can see in [this diff](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/diff01to02.txt) between version 1 and 2 of the RFC draft they dropped it. At the beginning it was in there.